# Online tool for calculating recursive sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, computer-science

If I have a sequence e.g. $$a_{n+1} = \frac13 *
(2a_n+\frac7{(a_n)^2})$$

and I have to calculate it for many iterations.. Is there an online tool which lets me choose a starting value and calculates the sequence for a certain maximum value of $n$ ? I searched around quite a bit, but did not find any tools that let me do this easily. Anyone knows a good option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good solution for doing Math computations in Cloud is [SageMathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/).